# jquery, find next element by class in table when rows dynamically created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I build a table dynamically in js where each row has same elements

```
         - input | input | **select** | **text** | **text** | **select**
Event 1  - input | input | **select** | **text** | **text** | **select** 
         - input | input | **select** | **text** | **text** | **select**  

Event 2     ...     ...       ....        ...        ...         ...

  ...

Event 10    ...     ...       ....        ...        ...         ...
```

As you can see the **select** has a class="place" for all 3 'td's
When I select a value I want it to update just the NEXT **text** and not all the **text** elements.

```
$("select.place").change(function () {
    $('.place').parent('td').next('#score').text("val")
});
```

This is updating all the **text** fileds with the val

I am generating the rows like this and appending them to a table :

```
            '<td> ' +
            '<select class="place"> ' +
            '<option value="1">1</option> ' +
            '<option value="2">2</option>' +
            '<option value="3">3</option>' +
            '</select>' +
            '</td>' +
            '<td id="score"></td>' +
            '<td id="score"></td>' +
            '<td>' +
            '<select class="place"> ' +
            '<option value="1">1</option>' +
            '<option value="2">2</option>' +
            '<option value="3">3</option>' +
            '</select>'
```

As you can see, I am not setting id's only class

I am not sure what the best way is to set the value after "select" and then conversely set the value before the second "select" per row.

Any help/ideas would be most welcomed.

Code for select change:

```
 $("select.place").change(function () {
    switch (parseInt($('select.place').val())) {
        case 1:
            $(this).parent('td').next('#score').text("10");
            break;
        case 2:
            $(this).parent('td').next('#score').text("8");
            break;
        case 3:
            $(this).parent('td').next('#score').text("6");
            break;
        default:
            $('select.place').val() == "0"
    }
});
```

CODE to loop through table to get values from objects

```
$("input:button").click(function () {

    var values;


    values = "";
    $("table tr").each(function () {

        $(this).find("td").filter(':visible').each(function (index) {
         if(index =5)
         {
            if ($(this).find("text").val() != undefined)
                values += $(this).find("text").val() + ";";
            if ($(this).find("label").text() != undefined)
                values += $(this).find("label").text() + ";";

             if ($(this).find("input").text() != undefined)
                values += $(this).find("input").text() + ";";

             if ($(this).find("select option:selected").text() != "")
                values += $(this).find("select option:selected").text() + ";";


        }
        });
    });

    values = values.replace(/\;;/g, ";");
    console.log(values)

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your change function you have a jquery selector that picks all elements with class="place" and applies the text to them.  Keep in mind that within most event handlers *this* refers to the html element that was activated.  So:

```
$("select.place").change(function () {
    $(this).parent('td').next('#score').text("val");
});
```

Comment: James

I have my change function like this:

Comment: $("select.place").change(function () {
        switch (parseInt($('select.place').val())) {
            case 1:
                $(this).parent('td').next('#score').text("10");
                break;
            case 2:
                $(this).parent('td').next('#score').text("8");
                break;
            case 3:
                $(this).parent('td').next('#score').text("6");
                break;
            default:
                $('select.place').val() == "0"
        }
    });

Comment: When I click in the second row, it adds the same val to "score" as the line above it.
How can I "reset" the value?

Comment: I added the code to the original post to make it formatted better

Comment: In your change function you still use `$('select.place')` in a some places rather than `$(this)`.  I don't know what you mean about resetting a value - seems unrelated to this problem.

Comment: $('select.place').val()  is always the first value I selected.
If I click on the select from row 2 and choose 3, when I debug the $('select.place').val() it is equal to 3.
It picks up the first select.

Comment: Yes, which is why you can't use $(".place") or $("select.place") in the event handler.  That is the whole point of my answer.  Use $(this) instead

Comment: One last question.
When I do :
$(this).parent('td').next('#score').text("val"); after selecting a value in dropdown, I am them looping through the table to get the value from the element
I cannot retrieve the value of the label that contains the value.
Code to get value is above

Comment: That'd be a whole new question.